# Will multiple FileSystemWatchers clash?

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher

I have a FileSystemWatcher on machine A watching a folder on machine B over a network. I want to create another FileSystemWatcher in a program on machine B to monitor the same folder locally. Will the second FileSystemWatcher interfere with the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a test and found that the FileSystemWatchers on both machines recieved notifications of events with interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

If both FileSystemWatchers are monitoring the same folder and event(s) (file rename, file arrived, etc.) and same filter pattern (*.txt, etc) then yes they will clash with eachother.

If any of the setup parameters are different then there will be no issue.